# PUT & PATCH methods not working(out-of-box) for JpaRepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Spring Boot 3.1.3

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "members")
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {
}
```

Entity(partial code):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }
```

he following endpoints worked as expected:

- GET (all employees)
- GET (employee by id)
- POST(add new employee)
- DELETE(delete employee by id)

however, the PUT and PATCH methods do not work:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-09-07T09:47:33.014+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/employees"
}
```

- Both PUT & PATCH [expect a save(...) method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.item-resource.supported-methods.put) in the Repository.
- [JpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) doesn't seem to have the exact signature.

I believe this is rooted in the default settings of spring-boot-starter-data-rest v3.1.3 wherein the PUT & PATCH methods need additional configuration but I might be wrong.

What do I need to do to make these methods work out-of-box?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace JpaRepository in EmployeeRepository interface wtih CrudRepository. It seems that JpaRepository does not have a save(...) method, only saveAndFlush(...) and this may cause the problem.